# Time Weighted Range Query in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to compute performance indices for a recorded tracking error, which is a timeseries persisted in Prometheus. I'm interested in:

- IAE: Integral Absolute Error
- ISE: Integral Squared Error
- ITAE: Integral Time Absolute Error
- ITSE: Integral Time Squared Error

For clarification, they are calculated as follows:

[image]

IAE and ISE should be straightforward. In case of ITAE and ITSE "older" error values have reduced influence and fresh ones are emphasized.

I've already created two Prometheus rules:

```yaml
rules:
- record: tracking_error:absolute
  expr: abs(tracking_error)
- record: tracking_error:squared
  expr: tracking_error*tracking_error
```

These enable me to query IAE and ISE:

```
# IAE
sum_over_time(tracking_error:absolute[1h])
# ISE
sum_over_time(tracking_error:squared[1h])
```

But I'm having difficulties designing queries for the time-weighted integrals ITSE and ITAE.

My current approach looks like this:

I create an additional set of rules persisting labelled timestamps:

```yaml
rules: 
- record: tracking_error:timestamp
  expr:  time()
- record: tracking_error:timestamp:labelled
  expr: label_replace(tracking_error:timestamp,"errorName","someError", "","")
```

Which in turn enables writing queries like:

```
sum_over_time(
  (
    tracking_error:absolute * ignoring (endpoint,instance,job,namespace,pod,service) group_left (errorName) (tracking_error:timestamp:labelled-(tracking_error:timestamp:labelled offset 1m))
  )[1m:]
)
```

It feels very icky. Is this even correct and is there another, better approach? I hope somebody can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better and not dependent on additional rules:

```
sum_over_time(
  (
    tracking_error:absolute 
    * 
    (timestamp(tracking_error:absolute)-timestamp(tracking_error:absolute offset 1m))

  )[1m:]
)
```